# How to fix the drawing of this circle in canvas using keycodes and clearRect()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to animate a circle on Canvas using the keyboard cursor keys. The problem is the clearRect() function is not being used properly and there is this bizzare line that draw with the circle when you use the cursor keys.

I have tried reordering the code including the cleaRect() function but that does not help.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="keycode.js" defer></script>
         <title>Example Javascript</title>
     </head>
     <body onload="setup()">
        <canvas width="1000" height="1000" style="border: 1px solid black">
          Your browser does not support canvas.
         </canvas><br>
        <input type="button" value="Move">
     </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the javascript code

```
console.log("Script is connected");

let canvas = window.document.querySelector("Canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let increment = 0;

function setup() {
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000); 
        increment += 200;
        ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2 - increment, canvas.height / 2, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        console.log(increment);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 10000, 1000); 
        increment += 200;
        ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - increment, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        console.log(increment);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 10000, 1000); 
        increment += 200;
        ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2 + increment, canvas.height / 2, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        console.log(increment);
    }


     if (event.keyCode === 40) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000); 
        increment += 200;
        ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 + increment, 100,             0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        console.log(increment);
    }
    }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of clearRect() is fine.  The problem is your code has just one open path which gets extended each time a key is pressed, so when you call ctx.fill() and ctx.stroke() it follows this longer and longer path.

Add beginPath() and closePath() to each of your cases and you will no longer get the
extraneous lines and such.

Like this:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2 - increment, canvas.height / 2, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```